# Meaning of "さすがにそこまではしません！”

Tags: grammar, translation

The basic context is this is in response to someone explaining themselves after an accusation was thrown at them. The speaker was a listener in this conversation who trusts the accused. I just can't wrap my head around the "そこまでは" part of the sentence. The まで in particular confuses me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think of そこまで as the degree of severity of the accusation. For example, if the accused is known to lie sometimes, but now he is accused of lying that actually got somebody hurt or dead. The accused is now trying to explain that (although he lies) he won't go that far. I hope you get the idea.